# MyGlass app doesn't show menu

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm trying to use MyGlass app for Android devices. I have achieved to pair my Glass with my android device (tablet).
It pairs perfect but just after it pairs, the app doesn't show anything and it returns to the initial state (showing a video + continue button).

I should say I'm using a Google Glass's friend so there is already an account associated. I've  associated another one (mine).

I don't know if the problem is that already exists a previous app or it is a bug from the app.

Answer (score 1):

You should be logged in with the same account, both Google Glass device and my glass app.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was bizarre to me that everything seemed to work and sync up, but then MyGlass just wouldn't show any options.  I didn't realize someone else had reset the Glass and used their own account on it.  Switching it back to my account resolved my issues.